# v2 API permissions [Case: 190112-003775]

Tags: linkedin-api

Migration process of V1 API permissions to V2 API Permissions

- LinkedIn Support advised to post this question in Stackoverflow.
- How do we migrate to the new API when the V2 permissions are missing?
- V1 = rw_company_admin (working)
- V2 = No access (Not working)
- The following permissions are missing:
- rw_organization_admin
- r_organization_social
- w_organization_social

How can we migrate to V2?

Answer (score 0):

From the migration docs:

"Looking to maintain access to rw_company_admin? Apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program to continue managing your Company Pages."

I believe you will only have access to v1 with the current rw_company_admin permission until March 1st.

Try to apply to the LinkedIn Marketing Developer Program click here: https://business.linkedin.com/marketing-solutions/marketing-partners/become-a-partner/marketing-developer-program

Not sure what their criterias are. My application was declined twice last year. Hopefully the third time's a charm.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the Info.  Sounds like there are some strict requirements to meet join the Marketing Developer Partner Program.  Does anyone know what the requirements are?  Did you get any feedback from your previous attempts?

Comment: Looking at the link provided "No application is required to access our basic
Company Pages APIs".  Looks like the migration to V2 will remove access to Company Pages.  Looks like V2 uses the concept of organization pages.  Does Company pages = Organization Pages?

Comment: @Glenn, yes company page = organization page. They don't give any specific reason. They simply send out a standard email saying "Alerting you that we are not able to approve your request at this time."

Comment: @ErvinKalemi how long did it take until you got an answer? I've been waiting over a month

Comment: @AlenBubich I just saw this. It did take around 45 days, but apparently that's because it somehow got stuck in the queue. Try to contact LinkedIn using their Developer Support site. That's how I managed to finally get my app reviewed and luckily got approved this time. Here's the link: https://linkedin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us